# How to handle .NET build time external dependencies?

Tags: .net, build, nuget, nuget-server

**What I have:**

- **ProjectCore and ProjectExtensions**. ProjectExtensions depends on some assemblies which are produced by the build of ProjectCore.
- both project are **built independently** as a build components by a general purpose custom internal build system

**The Question: Which is the best way to consume the deliverables of the Core project by the Extension project?**

- I'm not willing to use anything that is not integrated in VS
- If possible the dependencies should be resolved by without prebuild scripts

**Thoughts:**

- I can setup a NUGet adapter over our internal system but this will increase the complexity of our setup and will result in inconsistent builds. So I guess this is not the best choice.
- I can use e prebuild setup script which will resolve the dependencies but.. this is kind of external resolver difficult to debug.

Comment: You'll just have to get organized about it and ensure that the Core assemblies are always available at a predictable location.  And will be for the next 10 years.  Could be as simple as a file share on the build machine.  If you are going to copy then you'll need to get more organized about it :)